# Is "Create Product" a <Verb> + <Subject> or <Verb> + <Object>?

Tags: grammar, verbs, sentence

I am software developer and trying to develop a new language. I need to learn that basic information in English:

- *Create Product.*
- *Update Page.*
- *Stay Here.*

*Create*, *Update* and *Stay* are verbs, of course. What about *Product*, *Page* and *Here*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create Product = `<Verb> + <Object>`

Update Page = `<Verb> + <Object>`

Stay Here = `<Verb> + <Adverb>`

Note: *create*, *update* and *stay* are all conjugated as imperative here. When that is the case, there is in general no subject. As as example where there is imperative and subject: "You take your hands off me" (*you* is the subject).

Comment: Both of the objects are nouns, as well.